# Scroll the TextView automatically when entering a voice input in speech to text app

Tags: java, android

I'm preparing a project for the final exam at faculty "speech in text". I have a problem and I ask for help. I can not find out what the problem is and why TextView will not scroll the text up and when printing text in TextView does not display the sentence, it must be manually scrolled to see the latest entry.

My code:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

and

```
    myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    myText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Can you share your XML file? Is there a ScrollView?

Comment: Yes, I am share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
 myText.setSelection(mtText.getText.length())
```

it will be more useful if you write it into textWatcher.

Comment: If there is an `EditText`, this answer can be correct. He/She using `TextView`

Comment: I use TextView:

Comment: Is this the correct method because it reports an error? `myText.setSelection(mtText.getText.length())`

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. I tested, it works

```
textView.scrollTo(0,yourSpeechText.length-1)
```